# 500 internal server error on all pages

Tags: wordpress, migration

I have moved my site from [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mntextile/contact/) like to [here](http://mntextiles.com/). During the migration I changed the urls from all over the site so it could work properly in the new domain. Now I am getting **500** **Internal Server Error** message on all of the website's pages except the homepage. Please guide me how can I remove it?

Comment: @panther: The homepage is fine. The 500 error message appears on other pages except of the homepage.

Comment: Please explain in more detail the process you followed for migrating the site.

Comment: Have you gone to your permalink setting in the dashboard and hit "save"?

Comment: Did you do any change in .Htaccess file?

Comment: @rnevius: I went to the dashboard's permalink setting and hit save.

Answer (score 1):

I went to my website's permalink settings and choose a different permalink setting and hit save. The links started to work properly. Then I again went back and make permalinks the old custom posts way and it still is working properly.